# Protocol used by JDBC to connect to MySQL on different Host

Tags: mysql, database, networking, jdbc, windows-firewall

I want to know what is the protocol that is used by JDBC to connect to MySQL Database that is present on an other host.

My client has only http and https access restricted to his host. I want an application on an other host to communicate with that MySQL Database available on my client's host.

Please note my Client uses WINDOWS 2012 SERVER

He has asked me the protocols and ports my application is using to connect to MySQL so that he would enable them.

Request you to help.

Comment: Is it TCP that is used by JDBC to connect to MySQL on different host?

Comment: He doesn't need to know the protocol, which is proprietary, over TCP. He only needs to know port 3306.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt responses to all of you. I am loving stackoverflow more and more. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default mysql server uses  3306/tcp port but this is configurable. They should open up only the port that the server is listening on. Regarding the protocol it is mysql specific, you can find more info at the official [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/client-server-protocol.html)

Answer (score 1):

By default MySQL server listens on port 3306/TCP. See [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/connecting.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL uses its own binary protocol over TCP to destination port 3306 to connect to the database.  If you cannot get a path open betwee your client and the server for port 3306 maybe you can get the server configured to use a port that IS available to you.  It would depend on who has the stricter rules, the network admins or the DBA :-)